# Reputation being 1

Tags: support, reputation

I've seen some guys who actually had large amount of reputation, sometimes they're shown like that they're having only 1 reputation, with no badges at all.

Why is that happening?

Is that some error or can people choose to display their reputation as 1?

What's meaning of that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is that happening? What's meaning of that?

Those users you see with 1 rep are actually suspended for a certain time and for certain reason. You will see on profile page of those users a text like this,

> This account is [temporarily suspended](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for [a reason]. The suspension period ends on [date].

Reason and time can vary which you can see on the page I linked.

> Is that some error or can people choose to display their reputation as 1?

No, it's not an error nor people can choose to display their reputation as 1.